# FTP Folder Error The parameter is incorrect

Tags: ftp, windows-10

My client (X) often ftp ok to server to upload file to it.

One day the server admin (Y) change some setting so X can't connect to ftp server.

Then Y fix it, X can connect again but ftp server say incorrect password.

Then Y change password for X, I connect ok in my computer but when I go to X's computer, type ftp://10.19*.x.x  (ip of ftp server) it show error even before I can go to the username/password dialog

[image: aaa]

How could I fix this?

P/S: If I use Chrome browser in X's computer, it login successfully. Only error in windows explorer, but I can't use chrome to upload file to ftp server.

I already go to credential management in X's computer, no save password for ftp server to delete...

I'm kind of supporter between X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it.

Thank to [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-security/how-to-delete-or-reset-stored-ftp-site-passwords/133242cd-f4c6-4fa8-a74b-d98c8a617f4d), I open regedit and delete the old password folder in **HKCU/Software/Microsoft/FTP/Accounts**, then login again in explorer.